# Parsec if a match it found then throw error

Tags: haskell, parsec

I am trying to distinguish between Ints and floats in a parser. I have 2 parsers one for each int and float. However, I am having trouble getting into to fail on a '.'.  I looked for negating and look ahead and didn't seem to get and fruits.

I hope I am not duplicating any questions.

I had it working with looking at the next character that is not a '.' but that is an ugly solution.

**EDIT**: Added more code.

```
--Int--------------------------------------------------------------------
findInt :: Parser String
findInt = plus <|> minus <|> number

number :: Parser String
number = many1 digit

plus :: Parser String
plus = char '+' *> number

minus :: Parser String
minus = char '-' <:> number

makeInt :: Parser Int
makeInt = prepareResult (findInt  <* many (noneOf ".")  <* endOfLine)
    where readInt = read :: String -> Int
          prepareResult = liftA readInt
makeInt2 :: Parser Int
makeInt2 = do
  numberFound <- (findInt  <* many (noneOf ".")  <* endOfLine)
  match <- char '.'
  return  (prepareResult numberFound)
  where readInt = read :: String -> Int
        prepareResult = readInt
--End Int----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What does `findInt` look like (just helps having something to work off of)?

Comment: Added. Sorry I was not thinking when I put the code up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are best off actually combining the two parsers into one. Try something like this:

```
import Text.Parsec.String (Parser)
import Control.Applicative ((<|>))
import Text.Parsec.Char (char,digit)
import Text.Parsec.Combinator (many1,optionMaybe)

makeIntOrFloat :: Parser (Either Int Float)
makeIntOrFloat = do
    sign <- optionMaybe (char '-' <|> char '+')
    n <- many1 digit
    m <- optionMaybe (char '.' *> many1 digit)
    return $ case (m,sign) of
        (Nothing, Just '-') -> Left (negate (read n))
        (Nothing, _)        -> Left (read n)
        (Just m, Just '-')  -> Right (negate (read n + read m / 10.0^(length m)))
        (Just m, _)         -> Right (read n + read m / 10.0^(length m))
```

ErikR has a correct solution, but the use of `try` means that `parsec` has to keep track of the possibility of backtracking (which is a bit inefficient) when in fact that is unnecessary in this case.

Here, the key difference is that we can actually tell right away if we have a float or not - if we don't have a float, the `char '.' *> many1 digit` parser in [`optionMaybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v:optionMaybe) will fail immediately (without consuming input), so there is no need to consider backtracking.

At GHCi

```
ghci> import Text.Parsec.Prim
ghci> parseTest makeIntOrFloat "1234.012"
Right 1234.012
ghci> parseTest makeIntOrFloat "1234"
Left 1234
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `notFollowedBy` - e.g.:

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String
import Text.Parsec.Combinator

int :: Parser String
int = many1 digit <* notFollowedBy (char '.')

float :: Parser (String,String)
float = do whole <- many1 digit
           fracpart <- try (char '.' *> many digit) <|> (return "")
           return (whole, fracpart)

intOrFloat :: Parser (Either String (String,String))
intOrFloat = try (fmap Left int) <|> (fmap Right float)

test1 = parseTest (intOrFloat <* eof) "123"
test2 = parseTest (intOrFloat <* eof) "123.456"
test3 = parseTest (intOrFloat <* eof) "123."
```

Answer (score 0):

It is typically easiest to use applicative combinators to build your parsers - this makes your parsers easier to reason about and often you do not need monadic and backtracking functions of the parser.

For example, a parser for integers could be written as such:

```
import Text.Parsec hiding ((<|>), optional)
import Text.Parsec.String 
import Numeric.Natural 
import Control.Applicative 
import Data.Foldable

natural :: Parser Natural 
natural = read <$> many1 digit

sign :: Num a => Parser (a -> a)
sign = asum [ id <$ char '+'
            , negate <$ char '-'
            , pure id 
            ] 

integer :: Parser Integer 
integer = sign <*> (fromIntegral <$> natural)
```

A decimal number is an integer optionally followed by a decimal portion (a '.' followed by another integer), which is itself a number proper, so your parser can be written as

```
decimalPart :: Parser Double   
decimalPart = read . ("0."++) <$> (char '.' *> many1 digit)

integerOrDecimal :: Parser (Either Integer Double)
integerOrDecimal = liftA2 cmb integer (optional decimalPart) where 
   cmb :: Integer -> Maybe Double -> Either Integer Double
   cmb x Nothing = Left x 
   cmb x (Just d) = Right (fromIntegral x + d)
```

The definition of `cmb` is obvious - if the is no decimal part, then produce an `Integer`, and if there is, produce a `Double`, by adding the integer part to the decimal part.

You can also define a parser for decimals in terms of the above:

```
decimal :: Parser Double 
decimal = either fromIntegral id <$> integerOrDecimal
```

Note that none of the above parsers directly use monadic functions (i.e. `>>=`) or backtracking - making them simple and efficient.